# Swipe between UIViews within viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

Using a single `UIViewController`, I created two `UIView`s (one on top of another).  This was all done in `storyboard`.

I added gesture control functions:

```
-(void) SwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) gest_
{
if (self.view  == UIViewFirst)
    return;
else
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:UIViewFirst];
}

-(void) SwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *) gest_
{
if (self.view  == UIViewSecond)
    return;
else
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:UIViewSecond];
}
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` of the viewcontroller class, I simply did

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:UIViewFirst]
```

Now the views come up but they are blank.  I added labels to both views to see if this would.  No labels show up.  What am I doing wrong?  Should I be using something like `pageController`, `pageViewController`, or `UIScrollView`?  My goal is to be able to swipe between UIViews with content in them (top half view controller).

Comment: use pageviewcontroler is better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIPageViewController` handles all the transitioning for you, and wraps it up in nice, smooth animations too. You simply set the `viewControllers` property initially, then implement two delegate methods so that the controller knows what view comes next.

```
 public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?

 public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

My suggestion is that you subclass UIPageViewController and implement these methods, keep an array of weak instances of your view controllers on this class, then in `viewDidLoad` set the `pageController.viewControllers` property to be your array and in the delegate methods handle calculating current index and suggesting the next controller based on that.

Note that your 'views' will actually have to be contained in different view controllers to work with `UIPageViewController`.

More information can be found [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/)